# Connect Access database in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

please any one help me to connect local MS Access 2010 database to HTML using JavaScript. I want to retrieve the records (EmpName & EmpTelephone) by searching with their EmpID.

Please help. Im new to HTML.

Thank you

Comment: Kiyas, Just a friendly help here.  You have to give more information or the question will probably get closed.  It is extremely broad.  You don't really access a database with HTML, so everyone will need more context.  Don't let the negative votes discourage you.  It only means StackOverflow folks need more than you gave them.

Comment: Ok, well, you can't, not directly. This seems like you are trying to run before you can walk. I'd advise you spend more time reading tutorials because your a long way off the mark here.

Comment: It depends mostly on the host environment. Where is your JavaScript going to run? Node.js? Classic ASP? Somewhere else?

Comment: Usually you wouldn't want to have the front-end of a web application directly contact the database because that would require exposing your database credentials. Usually this would be something that happens on the backend. Where are you serving your webpages from in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

**First step,**

Open internet explorer , make sure you enabled ActiveX
[click here to watch video how to enable ActiveX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScfSbbxxnuQ)

**second step,**

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable ( make sure you selected the proper version x32bit , 64bit ,

**Third Step ,**

download this MDB file and place it on the same folder where the index.html is location [click here to download MDB File](https://files.fm/u/72nsr2jv)

**Final Step :** 
Copy and paste this code into html page ,

```
function AddRecord() {
//var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoConn = new ActiveX("ADODB.Connection");
//var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
var adoRS = new ActiveX("ADODB.Recordset");

adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='/\dbName.mdb'");
adoRS.Open("Select * From tblName", adoConn, 1, 3);

adoRS.AddNew;
adoRS.Fields("FieldName").value = "Quentin";
adoRS.Update;

adoRS.Close();
adoConn.Close(); 
}

function DeleteRecord() {
var adoConn = new ActiveX("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveX("ADODB.Recordset");

adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\dbName.mdb'");
adoRS.Open("Select * From tblName Where FieldName = 'Quentin'", adoConn, 1, 
3);
adoRS.Delete;
adoRS.Delete;

adoRS.Close();
adoConn.Close();
}

function EditRecord() {
var adoConn = new ActiveX("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveX("ADODB.Recordset");

adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='\\dbName.mdb'");
adoRS.Open("Select * From tblName Where FieldName = 'Quentin'", adoConn, 1, 
3);

adoRS.Edit;
adoRS.Fields("FieldName").value = "New Name";
adoRS.Update;

adoRS.Close();
adoConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: To add to Ahmed Sh answer- For accdb files using this seemed to work for me: ```adoConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\DB_Name.accdb'");```